# CodeIgniter fatal error: Call to a member function display_clients() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a program that basically does stuff with a database, I am having trouble with some of the functionality though, this is what it is supposed to do

```
public function clist() {
$this->load->model('list_model');
$fields = $this->list_model->listcli();
if ($fields === $this->list_model->listcli()) {
    $fieldl = $fields;
    $this->load->view('clientlist');
    $this->clientlist->display_clients($fieldl);
}

}
```

This loads the model which looks like this:

```
public function listcli()
{
 $this->db->list_fields('clients');
}
```

}

Then runs the model function `listcli` so that it will list all the fields in the clients database and puts the value into `$fields` I then call it `fieldl` and load a view that will show the data, the view looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> sup </p>
<?php

 function display_clients($fieldl)
 {

        ?>
        <html>
            <body>
            <p> sup2 </p>
                <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ($fieldl as $l) {
                ?>
                <li> 
                    <?php echo $l;?>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
    }
```

Then calls the function inside the view and passed the data from `$fieldl` into it.

but I am getting the error " Call to a member function display_clients() on a non-object in /codeigniter/src/application/controllers/clientlist.php on line 40"

line 40 is

```
$this->clientlist->display_clients($fieldl);
```

Can you help? Please and thank you.

(I know this kind of question has been asked before but they are always very specific to the code at hand so doesn't help me, I am really new to CodeIgniter so if you can keep any answer relatively simple I will be grateful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the second parameter possible to pass my data over into the view, not my own makeshift solution for it, CI accepts an object as a second parameter for the CI_Loader::view()

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you prepare the list in the controller and pass it to view via `$data` array?

```
$my_list = '<ul>';
foreach ($fieldl as $l) {
$my_list .= '<li>'.$l.'</li>';
}
$my_list .= '</ul>';

$data['my_list'] = $my_list;
```

then you can access it in view as `$my_list`. Just echo it where you need it.

EDIT:
AS per your own answer, yes - exactly. Using example above you would pass the `$data` to view as the second parameter:

```
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

Then in the View, you access `$data['my_list']` as `$my_list`, `$data['foo']` as `$foo` etc.

Comment: You can't just echo variables inside your view, they have to be loaded in, I have solved it now don't worry.

Comment: See my edit above. I thought my example was clear enough, apologies.